# I have an issue with ajax request in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-7

I need your help on the following please:

I'm working on a Q&A website with laravel and I'm trying to make a stars rating system for the answers with ajax, here is the code:

- Question view page which includes the answers:

```
//question code here
@foreach($answers->sortByDesc('created_at') as $answer)
<div>
<p>{{$answer->body}}</p></div>
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return saveRatings(this);">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="{{$answer->id}}">
<input type="submit"></input>
<div class="starrr"></div> // Rating stars
</form>
```

- Script:

```
<script>

    $(function (){
        var ratings = 0;
        $(".starrr").starrr().on("starrr:change" , function(event , value){

            var ratings = value;
        });
    });

    function saveRatings(form){ 

        var answer_id = form.answer_id.value;

        $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

        });

        $.ajax({
            url : "{{route('rating')}}",
            method : "POST",
            data : {
                answer_id:answer_id,ratings:ratings,    
            },
            success:function(response){

                alert (response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }  
    </script>`
```

- Route:

```
Route::post('rating', 'RatingController@store')->name('rating');
```

when I submit the form it doesn't direct me to the URL in the ajax request and throws an error msg :

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/1